# Is it OK to use manager classes as Singletons?

Tags: c#, data-access-layer

For each concrete class I have a Manager class. This class has methods like `GetAll()`, `GetById()`, `Save`, etc.

I've made these manager classes a Singleton because I always need one instance, and I have the ability to cache results. For example, when I call `GetAll()` and the next time I need this method again, the manager don't have to go to the database, it can return the cached results.

Is this a good approach? Or is there a better alternative way?

Comment: I don't know that there is enough information here to answer this concretely. I also am not sure there is a concrete answer. In some cases being able to cache the results would be a good idea. If the data is dynamic or the data set is large, caching it may not be a good idea (you get stale data, or add unnecessary memory pressure). I think it is very situational.

Answer (score 3):

What you call manager classes are really "repositories"

Repositories should only work at an aggregate root level, not one repository per class. E.g. if I have an Order class which has a collection of OrderItem, then an Order repository would exist that would have Get/GetAll methods - as the Order is the agg root in this case.

All repository classes would usually be singleton classes, where you can usually enforce this easily via an IOC container.

Overall, I would say your approach of one "repository" per entity is bad - stick to one repository per aggregate root instead.

Comment: I don't think I've ever implemented a repository as a Singleton.  I certainly use DI, but generally injecting a new instance each time.  I should add that I typically use "Once Per Request" model (web) and inject a single instance into the controller handling it. YMMV.

Comment: @bstack: thnx. One more question. How can I enforce this using a IOC container? Can you provide some (sample) code?

Comment: @tvanfosson: I don't see how to use DI in my situation. Can you explain that a little bit more?

Comment: @Martijn -- I use Ninject : https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/_pages (docs)

Comment: @tvanfosson: How can I use this with the manager classes? What do I inject and where is it injected into ?

Comment: @Martijn Well to inforce the "lifestyle" of a component such as a repository with an IOC container is quite easy. For example, with Castle - everything is singleton by default. Hence if you have two or more objects that both depend on the same repository, they will be injected with the "same" instance. You can override the lifestyle of the component by specifying e.g. lifestyle = "transient" which will give you a new instance of that object every time

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you provide an easy example? Or know a link where this is explained?

Answer (score 1):

Why not include them as part of the concrete class but static? Saves the need for two seperate classes.

Comment: Because that will violate the SRP principle.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are close to implementing the [Repository](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) pattern, but not quite all the way there.  I'd suggest looking into it.  I wouldn't make them Singletons -- it makes it too hard to mock them out for your unit tests so you end up adding back doors to defeat the Singleton for testing.  A cache makes a nice Singleton object, but why not simply share the cache this way instead of multiplying Singletons?

Comment: +1. I was writing my answer but I cannot tell anything else :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'why not simply share the cache this way instead of multiplying Singletons'. How do I share the cache? Do you mean, passing it around as a parameter?

Comment: @Martijn - you want to reference a single instance so either use a Singleton cache or use a DI framework configured to inject a single instance via the constructor.  To support unit testing, I've sometimes created an interface for a Singleton and injected an instance of the interface.  This allows you to mock for testing.  In the constructor, I check if the parameter is null (which is the case in production code) and, if so, default to the Singleton instance.

Answer (score 0):

For testing/mocking purposes, I would advise against using a Manager/Repository Singleton.

If you do want to cache results, then I would suggest delegating to a dedicated Cache class. Any static magic can be contained within the Cache class and your Manager/Repository's semantics can be kept clean.

From a Single Responsibility Principle point of view, I should be able to understand how a Manager/Repository works without having to understand your caching scheme.